# RTMP Streaming does not work from Docker container

Tags: docker

I have an application that streams data via RTMP with a command roughly like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel warning -f dshow -i - -vf crop=690:388:136:0 -r 30 -s 962x388 -threads 2 -vcodec libx264 -vpre baseline -vpre my_ffpreset -f flv rtmp://some.url.com/live/myStream.sdp
```

It works when I run it from the command line it works. But if I run it from the docker container it can't seem to connect to the RTMP URL

If I run the container using:

```
docker run -it container_name /bin/bash
```

I can ping the URL successfully so I don't know what the problem is.

**Update:**
Just to be extra clear, I want to be able to connect to an RMTP server that is on the Internet from within the Docker container. And it is this connection ffmpeg -> internet that can't be established.

Comment: It is definitely possible, as https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/captvty/ does (among other things) this

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, however it seems to me that this container does it in the opposite direction (internet -> proxy -> container) and then displays the stream. I want the opposite of that. Stream from the container